# Redefine an environment with options

Tags: floats, environments, wrapfigure

To write a report I am using the package `wrapfigure` which generates figures on a side and the text flows around it.

It is not news that it is very difficult to handle the spacing and positioning of `wrapfigure`, which requires a lot of manual tweaking. But when one gets it right, the results are beautiful; so it is worth the pain.

The problem at this point is that I am generating drafts and along editions I have to adjust every single `wrapfigure` environment to keep the draft even *readable* (the figures very easily overlap with the text). So what I thought is that I can use the `figure` environment for drafting and switch to `wrapfigure` only in the final version.

The `wrapfigure` enviromnent is used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[26]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
my graphics here
%\includegraphics{...}
\caption{...}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

So, I though I can redefine `wrapfigure` inside my document to be such that the above is translated as

```
\begin{figure} %arguments ignore
\includegraphics{...}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

So I imagine that I can do this:

```
% comment following line for final version
\renewenvironment{wrapfigure}[???]{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}
```

My problem is that `wrapfigure` takes three arguments that when working as a `figure` in the draft are going to be ignore.

**What do I have to put in `???` to have a compatible syntax?**

In otherwords how I redefine `wrapfigure` so that this line `\begin{wrapfigure}[26]{r}{0.5\textwidth}` behaves simply as `\begin{figure}` with the extra arguments ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `\begin{wrapfigure}` is

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[<number>]{<letter>}[<dimen>]{<dimen>}
```

You can use `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{wrapfigure}{omom}
 {\begin{figure}}
 {\end{figure}}
```

Comment: ok, I have to learn `xparse` once and for all. Do you know if it is possible to give a certain width to the figure float (not necessarily to the include graphics)? The captions now look too wide. And if so how can I pass the width argument to the internal figure argument?

Comment: @alfC Either use `caption` features like `\captionsetup[figure]{margin=3cm}`, if you load `caption`. Otherwise you have to patch `\@makecaption`.